# If $f_n\to f$ in measure, then $f_ng\to fg$ in measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f,g$ is a real-valued measurable function. Is it true that if $f_n\to f$ in measure, then $f_ng\to fg$ in measure?

The original question has the assumption that $g_n\to g$ in measure. And the question is to show $f_ng_n\to fg$ in measure. But I found that it boils down to show $f_ng\to fg$. I'm trying to use the analog of the proof in the case of the limit of functions, but the difficulty is that $g$ is not a constant, so $\frac{\epsilon}{g}$ is not fixed. I know this is duplicate, but I wonder if anyone could give me some hints. Thanks.

Comment: Is the measure finite? Do you assume $g$ to be integrable?

Comment: $g$ is not integrable. But the original question was to show $f_ng_n\to fg$. And the measure is finite. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: The convergence $f_n\to f$ in measure [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Topology) that $$\int\min(|f_n-f|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$
Now $$
\int\min(|f_ng-fg|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu=\int\min(|g||f_n-f|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu\ldots
$$

Comment: Thanks so much. I certainly saw this equivalence relation before! I don't immediately see, and I feel like it would be easier if $g$ is integrable.

Comment: Right. In fact the assumption that $g$ be integrable is not needed. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convergence $f_n\to f$ in measure [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Topology) that $$\int\min(|f_n-f|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$
Now, for any $A>0$,
\begin{align*}
\int\min(|f_ng-fg|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu&=\int\min(|g||f_n-f|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu\\[.4em]&=\int_{\{|g|\le A\}}\min(|g||f_n-f|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu+\int_{\{|g|>A\}}\min(|g||f_n-f|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu\\[.4em]&\le A\int\min(|f_n-f|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu+\mu(\{|g|>A\}).
\end{align*}
Thus $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int\min(|f_ng-fg|,1)\,\mathrm d\mu\le\mu(\{|g|>A\}).$$
Assuming $g$ to be finite a.e., the right-hand side tends to $0$ as $A\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! This is really nice... Just one question, can the first inequality be just the equality?

Comment: Yes it is an equality. I corrected it.